# What is the javascript equivalant for vbscript `Is Nothing`

Tags: javascript, vbscript

```
If Not (oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType") Is Nothing) Then

End If
```

I need to convert this to javascript. Is that enough to check `null`?

This was my lead's answer, plz verify this,

```
if(typeof $(data).find("BigGroupType").text() !=  "undefined" && $(data).find("BigGroupType").text() != null) {  

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript has two values which mean "nothing", `undefined` and `null`.  `undefined` has a much stronger "nothing" meaning than `null` because it is the default value of every variable. No variable can be `null` unless it is **set** to `null`, but variables are `undefined` by default.

```
var x;
console.log(x === undefined); // => true

var X = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(X.baz); // => undefined
```

If you want to check to see if something is `undefined`, you should use `===` because `==` isn't good enough to distinguish it from `null`.

```
var x = null;
console.log(x == undefined); // => true
console.log(x === undefined); // => false
```

However, this can be useful because sometimes you want to know if something is `undefined` **or** `null`, so you can just do `if (value == null)` to test if it is either.

Finally, if you want to test whether a variable even exists in scope, you can use `typeof`. This can be helpful when testing for built-ins which may not exist in older browsers, such as `JSON`.

```
if (typeof JSON == 'undefined') {
    // Either no variable named JSON exists, or it exists and
    // its value is undefined.
}
```

Comment: "`undefined` has a much stronger "nothing" meaning than undefined". I think you meant "than `null`". Also, `console.log(x === undefined); // => true` should be `false`

Comment: [NaN, Infinity, and undefined global objects are read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5#Changes_to_global_objects) in ECMAScript 5 (JavaScript 1.8.5 in non-strict, so your closing section is browser/version specific)

Comment: Ah, I thought it was just in ES5 strict mode. It appears I was wrong. In that case, warning not really needed anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: I did this,                                                             if(typeof $(data).find("BigGroupType").text() !=  "undefined" && $(data).find("BigGroupType").text() != null) {  this was my lead's answer, thats why I need to clarify this again.. thank for you all...

Comment: The `typeof ... != "undefined"` part isn't needed. `!= null` checks both `null` and `undefined` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for both `null` and `undefined`, this implicitly does so

```
if( oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType") != null ) {

}
```

It is the equivalent of:

```
var node = oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType");
if( node !== null &&
    node !== void 0 ) {

}
```

`void 0` being a bulletproof expression to get `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript equvalent for Nothing is `undefined`

```
if(oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType") != undefined){

}
```

Comment: Your code tests whether the value is `undefined` **or** `null`. They are different values. If you want to make sure it's `undefined`, you need to use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

This logic:

```
If Not (oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType") Is Nothing)
```

Can be written like this in JavaScript:

```
if (typeof oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType") != 'undefined')
```

`Nothing` would equal `undefined`, but checking against `undefined` is not recommended for several reasons, it’s generally safer to use `typeof`.

However, if the `selectSingleNode` can return other falsy values such as `null`, it’s probably OK to just do a simple check if it is truthy:

```
if (oResponse.selectSingleNode("BigGroupType"))
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:-

`(document.getElementById(“BigGroupType”) == undefined) // Returns true`

JQuery:-

`($(“#BigGroupType”).val() === “undefined”) // Returns true`

Note in above examples undefined is a keyword in JavaScript, where as in JQuery it is just a string.